# Change the decoration style of the Java Swing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

I'm trying to change the decoration style of the **`JFrame`**. I have tried the following code.

```
//...
static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(()-> {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("This is Title");
        frame.setSize(500, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

It changes the decoration style of the **`JFrame`** but it only works if the look and feel is set to *Metal*. If the look and feel is changed somewhere in the code in the run-time somewhere in the code as:

```
for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf: UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(laf.getName()) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
    }
}
```

Then, the look and feel get changed but the decoration of the **`frame`** get disappeared. As a result, I'm not able to move, resize, maximize, minimize and close the `frame`.

> #### Question 1:
>
> Is it possible to fix this problem?
>
> #### Question 2:
>
> Can I change the decoration style of the **`JFrame`** to make
>   look like **Visual Studio** title bar?

Comment: *"It changes the decoration style of the JFrame but it only works if the look and feel is set to Metal. If the look and feel is changed somewhere in the code in the run-time somewhere in the code as:"* This pair of sentences includes on incorrect statement that points to one basic fact. The frame decorations can only be changed **before the frame is displayed.**

Answer (score 1):

You can set the JFrame instance itself to be undecorated:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(()-> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("This is Title");
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

If you want it decorated differently (rather than undecorated) you'll have to write your own LookAndFeel.

Or try using the "SystemLookAndFeel" - this will roughly look like whichever Operating System you're running on. If that's Windows, it might end up looking a bit like Visual Studio...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you suggest some articles or documentation to create custom look and feel?